# "object github is not a member of package com" for a new Lift project

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I'm starting my first Lift project using the documentation here:

http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#LiftFromScratch

I've created my build.sbt as instructed. The walkthrough then says:

> Now that you have a the basics of an SBT project, you can launch the sbt console. It should load all the necessary dependencies, including the proper Scala version, and bring you to a prompt.

However, when I do that, I get the following error:

```
/Users/craig/myprojectdir/scala/build.sbt:9: error: object github is not a member of package com
seq(com.github.siasia.WebPlugin.webSettings :_*)
        ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

What's causing this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I has the wrong path/filename for `project/plugins.sbt`. Presumably that's what was loading the "com.github" plugin to load; since the file was misnamed SBT couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you find something in the recipe confusing? By which I mean...Is there any part of the "Lift From Scratch" recipe we can improve?

Comment: I think it's one of the better installation walkthroughs out there. I can't think of anything specific to improve it.